# Java regex replace all periods before first colon

Tags: java, regex

**Example input:**

```
this.is:an-example:3.0.3
```

I need to replace the periods before the first colon with forward slashes, as well as every colon with a forward slash.

**Needed output:**

```
this/is/an-example/3.0.3
```

Comment: Do you really need a regex? This can be done using simple string operations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
// sample input
String s1 = "this.is:an-example:3.0.3";

// `s2` contains the desired output
int idx = s1.lastIndexOf(':') + 1;
String s2 = s1.substring(0, idx).replace('.', '/').replace(':', '/') + s1.substring(idx);

// now we test it
System.out.println(s2);
=> this/is/an-example/3.0.3
```

Comment: I think you probably meant `.lastIndexOf()`; the sample input contains two colons

Comment: @fge on second thought, I think you're right :) fixed it!

Comment: Not sure about that: it seems the `.` need to be replaced only before the first `:` (but all `:` needs to be replaced)

Answer (score 2):

```
String input = "this.is:an-example:3.0.3:";
input = input.replaceAll("^([^:]*)\\.(?=[^:]*:)|:", "$1/");
```

Output:

```
this/is/an-example/3.0.3/
```

Comment: This is close, but it fails when there is more than one period before the first colon.

input:

    this.is.an:example:3.0.3

output:

    this.is/an/example/3.0.3

Answer (score 0):

You can use this replacement:

```
String result = yourstr.replaceAll("\\.(?![^:]*$)|:", "/");
```